# Channel-first convolutional layer in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

To generate tests for the operations of another system I am building, I am attempting to build a 1-layer ConvNet in Tensorflow, then extract the weights, biases, and outputs.

My system works in channel-first, hence I want my Tensorflow graph operate in this way too.  However my graph doesn't work right, since Tensorflow defaults to channel-last.

I have some random input data, which I generate using numpy.

```
import numpy as np

batch_size = 1
image_size = 5
image_channel = 3
shape = (batch_size, image_channel, image_size, image_size)
inputs = np.float32(np.random.random_sample(shape))
np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float,': '{: 0.b3f}'.format})
print(np.array2string(inputs, separator=', '))
```

I define my network structure thusly:

```
def network(x, mode_name):
    num_filters = 4
    filter_size = 2
    input_channels = 3
    stride = 1
    conv1 = conv_layer(x, conv_size=[filter_size, filter_size, input_channels, num_filters], 
                       stride_size=[1, 1, stride, stride], name=mode_name + "_conv1")
    return conv1

def conv_layer(prev_layer, conv_size, stride_size, name):
    W_initer =  tf.random_uniform_initializer(dtype=tf.float32)
    W = tf.get_variable(name + '_W', dtype=tf.float32, shape=conv_size,
                    initializer=W_initer)

    bias_init = tf.constant(np.float32(np.random.random_sample(conv_size[3])))
    b = tf.get_variable(name + '_b', dtype=tf.float32, initializer=bias_init)
    return tf.nn.conv2d(prev_layer, W, stride_size, data_format='NCHW', padding='VALID') + b
```

And my Tensorflow graph:

```
graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():
    tf.set_random_seed(1)

    with tf.variable_scope("simple_cnn") as scope:
        outputs = network(inputs, "simple_cnn")

    with tf.name_scope('init'):
         init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
```

Then I think I would extract my tensors like this:

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    kernels = tf.trainable_variables()[0]
    biases = tf.trainable_variables()[1]
    print("kernels:")
    print(sess.run(kernels))
    print("\nbiases:")
    print(sess.run(biases))
    print("\noutputs")
    sess.run(outputs)
```

Unfortunately this final operation fails with the error `Generic conv implementation only supports NHWC tensor format for now.`  It seems that [this used to be an issue with Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7967), but I am not sure if it still applies.  Does anyone know a way to get this to work on CPU?

Alternatively, would running the network in channel last mode, with the input data being of shape `[batch_size, image_size, image_size, image_channel]` still give me valid tests, assuming that I reshaped my tensors like so:

```
print("inputs")
inputs_chan_first = np.rollaxis(inputs, 1, 3)  
print(inputs_chan_first)

print("\noutputs")
outputs_chan_first = np.rollaxis(outputs, 1, 3) 
print(outputs_chan_first)
```

And leaving my bias and kernel tensors untouched?